# Has this constant wavy fill been hand drawn?

Tags: vector

This cover art features a curved wavy line that's used as a sort of fill.  It seems to precise to be handdrawn, but I've been unable to reproduce using patterns.  How might one go about creating something similar?

[image]

Comment: What'd you try?

Answer (score 2):

This is how it may have been created, using Illustrator:

- Create a shape:

[image]

- Go to `Effect -> Distort & Transform -> Zig Zag`

[image]

- Add a stroke to whatever thickness you're looking for:

[image]

- Hightlight object and go to `Object -> Expand Appearance`:

[image]

This is a starting point, if you want to modify the Zig Zag further you can use the `Direct Selection Tool` and modify the anchors individually:

[image]

- select the shape and do a gradient as the fill:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oops, you are absolutely correct. I'm in the middle of something, wasn't paying attention. Done.